# Add C++ projects to C++ working set when creating new project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse (Luna 4.4.1), added CDT for use with C++, then created a working set for Java and a working set for C++, so that it would switch sets automatically depending on which was the active perspective.

When I create a Java project, it allows me to check off a box to immediately add the project to the Java working set, but when creating a C++ project there is no such option.

As more projects get added to the workspace it gets harder and harder to find the project that was just created/imported, so is there a setting I could change or some file I could edit to add C++ projects to the C++ working set automatically upon creation?

(Possibly using a method which could be used for other types of projects as well.)

Comment: Eclipse has what it calls different "perspectives" and it automatically creates one for Java and another for C++. You shouldn't need to create working sets because the different perspectives should keep them separate. They should be there by default but in the left hand area there should be a specialized project viewer for either Java or C++ whichever perspective has been selected. You can open different project viewers from the menu `Window->Show View`. You can select `C/C++ Projects` or `Package Explorer` for Java.

Comment: To switch between the Java and C++ perspectives you can use the menu `Window->Perspective->Open Perspective` and select either C++ or Java.

Comment: Yes I'm using the proper perspectives, but those alone don't change projects visible depending on which one is active. 
Using working sets WITH perspectives though would allow you to only have the relevant projects visible in the Project Explorer.

Comment: Then try opening the proper project viewer for each perspective. There is a general non-specific project viewer but you need the language specific ones I mentioned.

Comment: When I select C/C++ Projects it includes my Java projects, unless otherwise specified using working sets.

Comment: Like I said, you need to select a different project viewer. For example go to the C++ perspective, then select `Window->Show View->C/C++ Projects`. Then in the left area of the screen there should be a C++ project viewer as one of the tabs (the generic project viewer [called Navigator] is probably the currently selected tab).

Comment: I think there's been a misunderstanding, what I meant was, when I go in the C/C++ Projects view, it still is including all of my Java projects, the only difference is that they show in a folder hierarchy view instead of the normal package hierarchy view inside of the projects.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case at the top-right of the C++ Project TAB there is a menu (down arrow). Select it and choose "Filters...". The window that pops up lets you select "Non C Projects" which causes it to ignore non C projects. (I assumed this was on by default but I may be wrong).

Comment: I found the option, but even after enabling the filter, the problem I see now is that it only works for open projects, and any that are closed show up regardless. (Same problem with "Non-Java Projects" flag in Project Explorer)

Comment: The same filter window contains an option for "Closed Projects" to eliminate them from display

Comment: Is there any way to only exclude C++ or Java projects when closed though?  I try to always close projects I'm not currently working in, so that I don't end up editing a file with the same name but in a wrong project, and for when using build all. Also, thank you very much for your help.